# UP2 IoT GrovePi - Get list of connected devices through programming (Python/C/CPP/Java)

Tags: java, python, c, raspberry-pi, grovepi+

We are working with **GrovePI** over **UP2 IoT Development kit**.

- [GrovePi](https://www.dexterindustries.com/grovepi/)
- [UP2](http://www.up-board.org/upsquared/)

We are struggling to get the list of connected devices /sensors. Is there a way to get the list of actively connected devices through programs?

We don't want to use ***Arduino***

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the official list of GrovePi Sensors supported](https://www.dexterindustries.com/grovepi-tutorials-documentation/).